Im trying to load the next level after all objects have been destroyed in my unity game (c#)
Im really new to coding and pretty much I have a game with a cannon at the bottom that shoots moving platforms above. I need to make it so that the next level loads after all the platforms have been destroyed. The top part of the code is fine. I have the cannon that shoots and destroys the platforms. But I cant get Unity to register the number of platforms that have been destroyed as increasing so that I can set the condition for the next level to load.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public int DestroyedPlatforms;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.up * speed;
    }
     // THIS PART BELOW IS THE PROBLEM
     public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("platform"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            DestroyedPlatforms++;
        }
     // THEN SOMEWHERE ELSE I WOULD CODE "IF # OF PLATFORMS DESTROYED = 3" OR HOWEVER MANY     IN THAT LEVEL, "LOAD THE NEXT LEVEL"
        }

It destroys the platforms fine, but in the inspector the number of platforms destroyed variable stays at 0 even after platforms are destroyed.

Sooooooooo as this is per bullet unless you manage 3 things with the same bullet which is unlikely given it hits a platform and destroys itself.. So, you need to consider that the bullet which now doesnt exist cant tell you if it took out a platform....

As mentioned above, you need to move the destroyedPlatforms tracking to an object that all bullets can notify.

yeah im pretty confused on this. I don't know what else I could move it to since it only seems to work at all when added to that part of the bullet script.

if the value is not updating in the Inspector, it may be that you are not seeing updates in real-time.
You can check if the variable is actually being updated by adding a debug log statement in the OnTriggerEnter2D method like this:
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("platform"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        DestroyedPlatforms++;
        Debug.Log("Number of destroyed platforms: " + DestroyedPlatforms);
    }

    // Check for level completion condition here
}

To load the next level after a certain number of platforms have been destroyed, you can add the condition in the OnTriggerEnter2D method or create a separate method to check for the condition. Here is an example of how you can implement this:
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("platform"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        DestroyedPlatforms++;

        if (DestroyedPlatforms >= 3) // Change 3 to the number of platforms required to load the next level
        {
            LoadNextLevel();
        }
    }
}

private void LoadNextLevel()
{
    // Add code here to load the next level
    Debug.Log("Next level loaded!");
}


Ohhh thanks bro that worked! but now the thing is when I test the "LoadNextLevel" code - I just did -   if (DestroyedPlatforms >= 3) {Debug.Log("Next Level)" - it only works if one bullet destroyed all three platforms. if one bullet destroyed each  platform or two destroyed one and one destroyed the last , it doesnt work

it looks like in the console, when one bullet destroys all three it registers it as 3 platforms destroyed, so the next level will load. But if one bullet destroys one platform three times, Unity registers it as "1 platform destroyed" three times, but it doesn't register this as 3 platforms destroyed which is the condition required for the  next level to load
